# Mongo connection string problem - host is empty

Tags: mongodb, connection-string

I'm using linux and I'm trying to use a localhost mongo conection string for my db so I can use it in Restart configuration.
I can connect without problems using the following:

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:MONGOPORT/DB_Y  --username USERXPTO --password 'PASS_WITH_SPECIAL_CHARS'
```

but when I try converting it to:

```
mongo mongodb://USERXPTO:CONVERTED_PASS@127.0.0.1:MONGOPORT/DB_Y
```

I keep getting

```
"Assertion: 13110:HostAndPort: host is empty"
```

Any idea?

This is my mongo version:

```
mongod --version
db version v2.4.14
```

Comment: your `mongod` version looks really old

Comment: indeed. RaspberryPI compatibility requirement.

Comment: You may have to check your mongo config file to see if bind_ip is set to 127.0.0.1

Comment: I checked it before and it is. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the URL in single quotes.

```js
mongo 'mongodb://USERXPTO:PASS_WITH_SPECIAL_CHARS@127.0.0.1:MONGOPORT/DB_Y'
```

Comment: Error: HostAndPort: host is empty at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
exception: connect failed

Comment: It seems to be an issue with your old mongo version. Please upgrade.

Comment: Can't... Raspberry PI 2 is not compatible with latest versions.